# Exact search with ElasticSearch 7.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to find an exact search for an url with ElasticSearch ("@elastic/elasticsearch": "^7.5.0").
I have configured my mapping like so:

```
const schema = {
      userId: {
        type: "keyword"
      },
      url: {
        type: "keyword",
        index: false,
        analyzer: 'keyword'
      },
      pageTitle: {
        type: 'text',
      },
      pageText: {
        type: 'text',
      }
    };

    await client.indices.putMapping({
      index,
      type,
      include_type_name: true,
      body: {
        properties: schema
      }
    })
```

I have tried different queries, and they looks like this:

```
body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: {
              match: {
                query: 'test stack',
                analyzer: 'keyword',  
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Or second attempt:

```
body: {
        query: {
          constant_score: {
            filter: {
              bool: {
                must: {
                  term: {
                    url: 'test stack'
                  } 
                }
              }
            }
          },

        }
      }
```

None of them work. I want to get only the results where the exact string 'test/stack' is found. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Example of data I'm trying to add:

```
[
{"url": "test stack",
"userId": "anotherTest",
"pageTitle": "not important",
"pageText": "not important",
"log": [1, 3, 7]
},
{"url": "test stack",
"userId": "anotherTest",
"pageTitle": "not important",
"pageText": "not important",
"log": [1, 3, 7]
},
{"url": "test stack",
"userId": "anotherTest",
"pageTitle": "not important",
"pageText": "not important",
"log": [1, 3, 7]
}
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a test document we can index that this is failing for?

Comment: I've added it to my initial post so I can format it. I am not getting any results back with either query. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make this work. Steps are:
1. Delete the index.
2. Delete the custom mapping function.
3. Create the index (with client.indices.create)
4. Index the first item (with client.index).
5. At this point, you can check in postman the dynamic mappings created by ElasticSearch (only visible after 1st item is indexed, by what I could tell). You can make a get request at http://localhost:9200/history/_mappings, and the response should look something like this:

```
{
    "history": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "fullTitle": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "log": {
                    "properties": {
                        "startTime": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "timeSpent": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "protocol": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "totalTimeSpent": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "totalVisits": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "userId": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, any field indexed as text has attached another field, called keyword, which can be used for exact matches.
6. The query to get the exact matches looks like this:

```
   const result = await esClient.search({
      index: 'history',
      body: {
        query: {
          term: {
            'url.keyword': {
              value: toInsert.url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

At this point you should receive results only in case of exact match for the field "url" in my case. Hope this helps somebody else. Thanks @ibexit for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. The mapping defined for the url field says

   url: { 
    type: "keyword", 
    index: false, 
    analyzer: 'keyword'
   },

   If you define `index: false`, the field will not be searchable at all. Using the following mapping should work properly:

   url: {
     type: "keyword"
   }

   See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html for more detailed information
2. The keyword mapped fields will not match using the `match` query which is designed to query text fields. Please use the term query instead for keyword fields. Please notice the example below using the Elasticseaech Query API:

   GET /_search
   {
     "query": {
         "term": {
             "url": { <<= the field to search
                 "value": "test stack" <<= the searched value
             }
         } 
     }
   }

   Here is the according documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

BTW: keep in mind that you need to reindex the data after a mapping change

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the changes and it works only if the term contains no separators (no whitespaces, slashes, etc). So I guess somehow this still gets tokenized. My purpose is to store here urls, which will need to be treated as terms, so this solution still doesn’t cover my need.

Comment: Have you removed the analyser from the mapping and query too? Have you build up a new index and have you reindexed the data?

Comment: Yes. I have left only type:keyword in the mapping, and my query is now as follows:       body: {
        query: {
          term: {
            url: {
              value: 'abc/',
            }
          }
        }
      }. After indexing this value ('abc/), the query above returns nothing. However, if I index 'abc' and then look for this term, then I do get a result. I have deleted the index and re-created it, as I don't have relevant data so far.